# createObjectURL file convert to filereader format (xhr upload)

Tags: html, upload, xmlhttprequest, filereader

I have written a upload tool with html5.

I create a file path with URL.createObjectURL(file); // file = a file from filelist -> dataTransfer (input multifile select)

```
<div class='photo' style='background:url(" + Link + ") center center; background-size:cover'></div>
```

Now will I be able to read the file infos with the old method (file reader)

```
file = $('.Foto').css('background-image').replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/,'');

console.log(file); //blob:http://localhost/16264d2d-572e-4f3c-88cb-9d081147ed3a
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Now I am getting an error from firebug:

"TypeError: Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer is not an object"

the self error with:

```
readAsBinaryString()
readAsDataURL()
readAsText()
```

I need this for other informations from the file:
example: file.size, file.name, file.type

I will upload big files in blobs:

```
fileb   = file.slice(start,end);
formData.append("afile",fileb);
xhr.open("POST", Link, true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

My problem is, I need a upload tool with multifile select and multi drop (dropzone). The files are only uploaded, when the user click on the button "now upload the files".

The big problem is the html5 API filelist.

When I select new files with drap and drop or file explorer, is the old list empty.

Can I merge (push) new files to the filelist?